# Where should this question go?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252050/how-can-i-download-the-blender-open-movies-in-the-highest-quality-available) about downloading Blender open movies - and explain in the question why I need to download them instead of just watching them online. I have an answer, which I haven't checked out yet, but it's closed as not being specifically about using Blender.

What I don't follow is where, if not in the Blender board, this question would be appropriate to ask. I've asked in a few places and it's been ignored, so I went to the one place I figured I'd be most likely to get an answer. While it's not a question about downloading, say, Blender itself (and there are such questions, also about downloading documentation), I'm asking about looking at the best examples of demos of work done in Blender.

I'm asking about getting what I think would be considered the best examples of what Blender can do, considering they're done by the Blender Foundation as test animations to push the limits of the program and to showcase it. While it's not asking about actual documentation, it fits very much in the field of trying to learn Blender and what it can do. While this doesn't go into a "how to" about something, seeing examples and demos are a major part of learning a system for visual learners.

So if this is not the right place to ask about something like that - about examples that can be guides for what people want to do with Blender or want to know what it can do - then where, on SE, should I be asking it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it would be accepted well, but you could try [movies.se] perhaps. I don't know the entirety of their scope to be able to say for sure that it would be on/off-topic for them. (You could always ask about scope in their meta or even chat also.)

Comment: I think you've asked a question that has fallen through a crack.  Many of the forums that should be appropriate will hesitate to answer "where do I download" questions because they don't want to risk dealing with pirating -- even though your particular question is perfectly legitimate.  You might try the Blender foundation's own forums, but I can't think of any other.

Comment: @MartyFouts I think you're right - it's between the cracks. I find, more and more, I search and am glad to find answers on SE sites, but am less and less inclined to ask my questions here and, instead, prefer to ask questions in web forums on the topics in question. I think SE is becoming more and more focused on following their rules and kicking marginal questions to the curb and I think that's making SE more a forum for questions by people who already know what they're doing in a topic and kicking to the curb people who are new and don't always have questions that fit SE's precise rules.

Comment: @MartyFouts Setting this as a separate comment, since I think it's a 2nd subject: I went to the Blender site first and did try a few places there. Blender is one subject where I rely more on other forums than SE for the reasons stated in the last comment: SE and SE mods seem more focused on policing the questions asked than in making sure people who need help get it.

Comment: Well sounds like it could be one of the items in the extensive list of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender , otherwise seems like a good fit for [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Maybe it's semantics, but I'd skip the "otherwise." I checked, since I had tried to get answers elsewhere first and I overlooked the Blender Artists Forum. (I thought I had posted it there - must have missed it.) But it seems to me it'd be a good item to include in any resource list either way.

Comment: Everyone is free to add content to that post, feel free to contribute if you find an answer. All Blender Studio movies should be available for download from the Blender cloud, albeit behind a symbolic paywall.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I may add just the link to the page with all the open movies listed. While it doesn't have downloads, for people on "normal" internet, it's fine. I think Marty Fouts is correct, that to get the downloads, one needs to subscribe. I'm considering that and likely will later in the spring - after we get Starlink internet and after I've finished a lot of needed work on our lot and driveway (it's 1/2 mile long - still not fully finished) and have time to get more into Blender.